# Import Sublime Text 3; Not In Path

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for Sublime Text 3 that uses antlr4. I've brew installed antlr4 onto my Mac, but obviously Sublime can't use it because antrl4 isn't in its path. I don't want to completely overwrite sublime's path because I need to access sublime and sublimeplugin modules. Rather, I'd like to append the antlr4 directory to Sublime's path. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do so.

I've tried the hacky solution of copying the antlr4 directory into my Plugin's directory, but `from antlr4.FileStream import *` still gives a `ImportError: No module named 'antlr4'` error.

Comment: If it's in your plugin directory and your plugin is named MyPlugin, you need to say `from MyPlugin.antlr4.FileStream import *` instead. Also I'm pretty sure this is how you are meant to add external dependencies to your Sublime plugins so that everything is self contained.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thank you!!

Comment: You can also put it directly into the Packages folder and import as you did it first. If you want to release your package you can use [dependencies](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/dependencies) and release `antlr4` separate as a dependency.